# .htaccess not redirecting / to /index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using this htaccess code, located in the directory development.local/web/, to redirect all of my paths to development.local/web/index.php file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /web
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

right now, I have development.local/web/ as my base url. so all paths must redirect to development.local/web/index.php as of right now all urls will redirect properly except development.local/web/ which gives me a 503 Forbidden Error.

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteBase /web`?

Comment: Yes, all files for my project are stored in development.local/web/

Comment: But there is no `/web/` in your URI `development.local/foo/bar`. Is `/web` your DocumentRoot?

Comment: No, /web would be considered a subdirectory of development.local and contains the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you don't have `DirectoryIndex` setup.

Keep this in your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Terrific troubleshooting—bull's eye on the first try, +1 :)